# How can I set the program time in seconds?

Tags: java, time

I want to give the program time in java. How can I get the time in seconds? 
This is my program:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    long start = System.nanoTime();
    System.out.print(start);
}
```

For example when i run the program show 7955739220574 nano time. that mean's 7955 second.
Is this time is really for this program!!!!!?
Thank you.

Comment: Homework assignment?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please note that [`System.nanoTime()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#nanoTime()) returns the time in nanoseconds which passed since an arbitrary point in time, not necessarily the beginning of your program. [`System.currentTimeMillis()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#currentTimeMillis()) will give you the absolute time in milliseconds since the Unix epoch (Jan 1, 1970).

If you want to measure the duration of something you can do:

```
long startTime = System.nanoTime();
// ... the code being measured ...
long estimatedTime = System.nanoTime() - startTime;
```

... as showed in the docs i linked. If you want it in seconds you should divide `estimatedTime` it by 1 billion.

Answer (score 1):

You could use TimeUnit:

```
TimeUnit.SECONDS.convert(time, TimeUnit.NANOSECONDS);
```

Answer (score 0):

Divide the result you get in nanoseconds by 1 000 000 000.

Answer (score 0):

`1 nanosecond` is `10^-9 * 1 seconds`.

so to get seconds using nano seconds, you need to divide the value of `Start` by `10^-9`